# How to import JS libraries correctly

Tags: javascript, import, draggable

I've only been programming for a few weeks and have a question. I want to learn some frameworks and found draggable js (from Shopify.github.io) and want to try it out a bit locally. But no matter how I try it, I can't embed it. I have a HTML file where I simply integrated everything via cdm and a Javascript file where I just want to move some Div elements, but I always get the following error when I want to import draggable:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

My Js Code and Html :

```
Import { Draggable } from '@shopify/draggable/src/Draggable/Draggable.js'

var elementToDrag = document.getElementById('elementToDrag');
draggable(elementToDrag);
...  



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shopify/draggable@1.0.0-beta.6/lib/draggable.bundle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/app.js" ></script>
```

if I try it on codepen it works fine but I would like to test it in my own development environment. Thanks for any help

Comment: Import -> import

Comment: If changing ```Import``` to ```import``` doesn't solve your issue then please add more details about your local development environment.

Comment: i m just using Atom and I just have a HTML File, CSS File and one JS File. Pretty simple so far.  I changed the import and still the same error. Even when I create a project with npm and install it + everything via CDN in my head section, I still get the same error :(

Comment: and if I add type="module" in my head section where I import the drag.js file I get :TypeError: Module specifier does not start with "/", "./", or "../".